# How to unload Windows Kernel Mode Driver from the inside?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, windows-kernel

I'm writing a Windows kernel driver and i'm trying to implement the following.

Suppose the driver has been called from user mode via [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with a specific IOCTL code. How can driver unload itself in this situation? In other words, how to achieve the same behavior as running `net stop` command?

More precisely, what should i write when implementing [DispatchDeviceControl callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
NTSTATUS IoctlDeviceControl(PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject, PIRP pIrp) {
    // some code...

    switch (ioctlCode) {
        case IOCTL_MY_UNLOAD:  <---
        ...
    }

    return Status;
}
```

Comment: Try using `IoDeleteDevice()`, but this functionality highly depends upon type of your driver. If you have a usermode app, you can use WIN32 apis to stop the service similar to `net stop`, but done programatically.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ZwUnloadDriver` Kernel function!

**Documentation:**

> The ZwUnloadDriver routine unloads a driver from the system. Use this
>   routine with extreme caution. (See the following Remarks section.)

**C/C++ Definition:**

```
NTSTATUS ZwUnloadDriver(
  _In_  PUNICODE_STRING DriverServiceName
);
```

**MSDN Source:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567117(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can a driver unload itself with this call? That seems problematic, given that a thread is currently executing code in that driver. When ZwUnloadDriver returns, the thread still exists but the driver image is no longer loaded. How can that work?